# ifstream codes do not work

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying the following codes to read data from file and then trying to test if they work by cout data to screen, but I cannot figure out what wrong with this. It only prints out the last line of my data file. Can you please have a look? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

struct Data {
vector<double> cow_id;
vector<double> age_obs;
vector<double> dim_obs;
vector<double> my_obs;
vector<double> mcf_obs;
vector<double> mcp_obs;
vector<double> mcl_obs;
vector<double> bw_obs;
vector<double> bcs_obs;

void read_input (const string filepath)

{
ifstream data_in (filepath.c_str());
if (!data_in)
    {cout<<"Failed to open"<<endl;}
 else
    {
    double id,age, dim, my, mcf, mcp, mcl, bw, bcs;
    string dummy_line;
    getline(data_in, dummy_line);
    while (data_in>>id>>age>>dim>>my>>mcf>>mcp>>mcl>>bw>>bcs);
        {
        cow_id.push_back(id);
        age_obs.push_back(age);
        dim_obs.push_back(dim);
        my_obs.push_back(my);
        mcf_obs.push_back(mcf);
        mcp_obs.push_back(mcp);
        mcl_obs.push_back(mcl);
        bw_obs.push_back(bw);
        bcs_obs.push_back(bcs);

        }
        data_in.close();
    }

    size_t size=age_obs.size();
   for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
       cout<<cow_id[i]<<'\t'<<age_obs[i]<<endl;
   }
  }

  };

  int main()
   {
     Data input;
     input.read_input("C:\\Data\\C++\\learncpp\\data.txt");

     }
```

Comment: You have a `;` ending the `while` loop. Remove it and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: Oops, how could I not find it :(. Thanks Sahu.

Comment: By the way, would you please tell me how should we handle the case if the data file contains some missing values and currently indicated as "NA". Thanks

Comment: It will be better to close this post and as the question in a new post.

Comment: Yeap, I will do that. Thanks